# Does MySQL/InnoDB checksum my data?

Tags: mysql

Harddrive bit-rot [does happen](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/8794/). Does MySQL go about making sure that bit-rot does not happen to my data stored in the database? Ie. does it make any row-level checksumming, or table-level checksumming? I guess it's not dealing with error correcting codes.

Let's stick to InnoDB and MyISAM for this answer (as they are the most common DB engines).

Comment: I didn't check. but i would guess both of them are much too optimized for performance to do any checksumming.

Comment: Your storage media does checksuming - so if you lost/flipped bits, MySQL is never going to see the data to test any checksum it adds.

Comment: syncbean, so would you say bit-rotting is a non-issue at the application layer?

Comment: It entirely depends on your media. A single sata/ide hard drive doesn't do checksums, so a flipped bit wouldn't be detected. A raid-1 array would detect it, and a three disk raid-1 would be able to repair it. SSDs tend to do checksums to detect when pages start failing due to wear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Innodb checksums each data page and by default verifies that checksum each time the page is read from disk: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_checksums

I'm not sure that myisam has internal checksumming, but there are a bunch of external utilities that can verify the integrity of myisam tables/data (myisamchk, etc).

Between the two, I think Innodb is a much better choice for data integrity if that is what you're looking for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You also can use the `innochecksum` tool to verify any binary backups you make as well. Url: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innochecksum.html

Comment: This could also be useful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-performance.html#innodb-crc32-checksum